# How to configure xemacs to recognize database specified in .sql-mode?

Tags: sunos, xemacs, sql-mode

I am running xemacs with a .sql-mode file containing the following:

```
 1  (setq sql-association-alist
 2        '(
 3      ("XDBST (mis4)  " ("XDBST"        "xsius"  "password"))
 4      ("dev             " ("DEVTVAL1"   "xsi"    "password" "devbilling"))
 5   ))
```

When I log in to the database in xemacs by selecting Utilities->Interactive Mode->Use Association, it logs me in but it does not pick up the database parameter.  For example, when I log in to "dev", it logs me in but then when I do "select db_name()" it yields csdb instead of devbilling.  It appears that it is picking up the default database associated with the user and ignoring the database parameter.  How do you configure xemacs so that it picks up the database parameter specified in .sql-mode when the option is selected?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and xeamcs is using sql-mode.el which on my system is in /usr/local/xemacs/lisp/sql-mode.el to login with SQL Mode.  The code in the file does not use the database specified in .sql-mode in Interactive Mode.  It does, however, use the database specified in .sql-mode in Batch Mode.  You can use Batch Mode as a workaround.